# PostgreSQL database for GITLAB - Grant privileges only to user PUBLIC?

Tags: postgresql-9.6

I manage a Postgresql database for a GITLAB application.
The developer provided me with a backup file for migrating his database to a new server that contains the following statements:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE <dbowner> IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON SEQUENCES  FROM <dbowner>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE <dbowner> IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT,USAGE ON SEQUENCES  TO PUBLIC;

ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE <dbowner> IN SCHEMA public REVOKE ALL ON TABLES  FROM <dbowner>;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE <dbowner> IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE ON TABLES  TO PUBLIC;
```

Why would you revoke all privileges from the database owner & grant them instead to PUBLIC?  I thought that granting privileges to user PUBLIC is a big security risk?